# Help! Drywall anchor doesn't go through metal

Tags: walls, anchor

I'm trying to install a heavy mirror and I've drilled through some thin metal...now I'm trying to put a plastic wall anchor through it and it won't go in.  I've done it properly for one side but that's because this side is purely drywall.

What should I do??  I don't want to damage my walls any further...[image]

Comment: Looks like you hit a stud , pull the anchor and just use a screw.

Answer (score 2):

Normally I avoid them, but there's a "screw-in" drywall anchor (it's metal) that can work with studs. The one I have is called EZ-Ancor but I've seen others. You should be able to find a small pack of them and add one that will grip the stud. That might solve your problem because the screwing action of the anchor should fit in the hole you've drilled in the metal stud.

Comment: +1 on what would  be one the ways to salvage the oversized hole that was drilled for the plastic anchor. In the metal stud, it would grip very well. I do not care for the anchors myself, but in this occasion, it will be a reasonable fix.

Comment: Thank you both for your help!  Just to clarify I have a 3/8 hole in my drywall AND my metal stud.  The metal anchor will still work in this case right ?  I'm not going to be able to use a screw because there's already a huge hole.

Comment: At this point the drywall hole is larger because I needed to tear out the plastic anchor =(

Comment: Yes, the anchor (which is a screw itself) should not only plug the hole, but grip the metal stud too